# RVM Ruby Installation failed with no checksum

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm, centos6

I am going crazy with this problem. I've installed rvm and re-installed a million times, but it just isn't working.

I have a fresh install of centOS 6.3 and when I go to install rvm, it completes, but then gives me a weird error when installing ruby.  Here is the trace:

```
[pushprod@ruby-prod webapps]$ \curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3     --ruby
    ######################################################################## 100.0%
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1062k  100 1062k    0     0   609k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1533k

Installing RVM to /home/pushprod/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /home/pushprod/.bashrc /home/pushprod/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /home/pushprod/.bash_profile /home/pushprod/.zprofile.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.io/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues run 'rvm requirements' or read 'rvm notes'

Installation of RVM in /home/pushprod/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/pushprod/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# pushprod,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and
#   more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne



rvm 1.20.9 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: centos/6.4/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p195.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for centos, might require sudo password.
There is no checksum for 'https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6' or 'RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6', it's not possible to validate it.
This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. You may want to
update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

There is no checksum for 'https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm' or 'epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm', it's not possible to validate it.
This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. You may want to
update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

error: /home/pushprod/.rvm/archives/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6: import read failed(2).
error: open of /home/pushprod/.rvm/archives/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm failed: No such file     or directory
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be? this is killing me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: it looks like a bug, bugs should be reported to the project => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same issue. Try installing the EPEL RPM referenced in the error message;

`error: open of /home/<username>/.rvm/archives/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm failed: No such file or directory`

Download it from the following URL(also referenced in the rvm output):
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

then enter;
`rvm get stable`

The above steps have seemed to get rvm running properly for me.

Comment: It works! You may install EPEL with help of [that tutorial](http://ithelpblog.com/os/linux/redhat/centos-redhat/how-to-install-epel-repository-on-centos-6-4-or-redhat-6-4-rhel/).